# Ajax - Parse oData Response

Tags: ajax, odata

I have an ajax call that gets data from a REST api.

```
                        $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:52139/odata/WEB_V_CIVIC_ADDRESS",
                        data: { enteredText: "'" + $('#addressTextField').val() + "'" },
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        ContentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            response($.map(data.accountaddressList, function (item) {
                                return { 
                                    item: item.civicaddress,
                                    value: item.accountNumber,
                                    label: item.civicaddress
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                        error: function (data, xml, errorThrown) {
                            alert('Error loading address list: ' + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
```

The odata returned from that call looks like:

{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:52139/odata/$metadata#WEB_V_CIVIC_ADDRESS/AValues.Classes.Entities.AccountAddress","value":[
    {
      "@odata.type":"#AValues.Classes.Entities.AccountAddress","accountNumber":88887,"rowNumber":0,"civicaddress":"123 Fake St"
    },{
      "@odata.type":"#AValues.Classes.Entities.AccountAddress","accountNumber":88888,"rowNumber":0,"civicaddress":"321 Faker St"
    }
  ]
}

So the current code throws an 'Undefined' error on the line: response($.map(data.accountaddressList, function (item) {

How do I map the 'civicaddress' and 'accountNumber' from each value in the odata response to 'item'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, needed to change it to  response($.map(data.value, function (item)